# How can I ensure my content on my website fits within size portion of the browser?

Tags: html, css

I'm building my own website for an assignment project for college and wondering if anyone could help me with this major issue I'm having.

When I open the html file of my website on my macbook which have the dimension 2880 x 1800 at home I have to adjust the view size to 80% on the google chrome bowser for the webpage to be in size proportion. However, at college the website is automatically in size proportion. My concern is when the person who is reviewing my website it's out of size proportion for them.

Is there a code which can adjust the website view depending on the users monitor size automatically?

I have seen some websites use the following html types of code. Does this help with the position of the content to fit and adjust to the dimensions of the monitor and browser.

```
.image:hover {
  -webkit-transform:scale(1.2); 
          transform:scale(1.2);

max-width: 100%;
```

When I open a online portfolio if I use the "Enter Responsive Design Mode" in the "Develop" option on my macbook you can clearly see the way I coded the content it is not in size proportion and has moved.

[image]

Here is actual view I want it to look like, I have loaded up my site in the google chrome browser and changed the view to 80%.

[image]

In addition, here is a view of my site on Safari, it's all out of alignment.

[image]

Furthermore, below is an example of a web developers portfolio which content fits exactly in size proportion on google chrome and safari no matter what dimensions of the monitor is. **(This is what I'm trying to achieve)**

[image]

Overall, I want to know if there is code which can fit my content to the users screen like how the web developers website looked above in the example therefore, when I open my site on **google chrome, safari and mobile** the content will look perfect and all aligned how I want it to look. Like this.

Lastly, below is my HTML & CSS for anyone who is willing to help me to review if I have included something wrong within the coding or could add anything which will help me achieve purpose of the post.

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <html lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Liam Docherty Digital Portfolio</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>
 <body>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top"> 
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/60x60" alt="Your Brand Name"></a>
                    <h1 class="nav-title">Liam Docherty's Digital Portfolio</h1>
                </div>
                <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                            <li><a href="#">Home</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="dropdown">
                                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">About Me <span class="caret"></span></a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                    <li><a href="#">Action</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li><a href="#section3">Contact</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Something else here</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Separated link</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li class="dropdown">
                                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Units <span class="caret"></span></a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                    <li><a href="#">Action</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Another action</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Something else here</a>
                                    </li>

                                    <li><a href="#">Separated link</a>
                                    </li>

                                    <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="#">Clients</a>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="#contact-me">Contact Me</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                      </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
                    </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
        </nav>


    <section id="section1" class="section1">
      <div class="hero">
          <div class="shape"></div>
          <div class="shape2">
              <p>kjjjjjjjjjkjjjkkjkj</p>
          </div>
        </div>





      <a href="#section2"><i class="fa fa-angle-down" style="font-size:100px;"></i></a>

    </section>
    <section id="section2" class="section2">


      <a href="#contact-me"> <i class="fa fa-angle-down" style="font-size:100px;"></i></a>

    </section>

    <section id="contact-me" class="contact_section section3">


      <a href="#section1"> <i class="fa fa-angle-up" style="font-size:100px;"></i></a>

    </section>
    <script   src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js" integrity="sha256-16cdPddA6VdVInumRGo6IbivbERE8p7CQR3HzTBuELA="   crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<footer>
    <div class="footer">
        <h2 class="footertext">Copyright © 2017 Liam Docherty's Site. All rights reserved.</h2>
    </div>
 </footer>     
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
<style>
    body {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
    .navbar.navbar-default {
      background-color: #4D5061;
      height: 10vh;
      z-index: 100;
    }
    .navbar.navbar-default ul {
      list-style-type: none;
      text-align: right;
    }
    .navbar.navbar-default ul li {
      display: inline-block;
    }
    .dropdown-menu li { 
        text-align:center 
    }
    .dropdown .dropdown-menu {
      background-color: #4D5061;
    }
    .dropdown .dropdown-menu a {
      color: white;
    }
    .navbar.navbar-default ul li a {
      display: inline-block;
      padding: 3.5vh 8px 4px;
      color: white;
      text-decoration: none;
      font-size: 14pt;
      font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    }
    .navbar.navbar-default ul li:after {
      content: '';
      position: absolute;
      right: 50%;
      bottom: 0;
      left: 50%;
      height: 3px;
      background-color: #FFFFFF;
      border-radius: 9px;
      transition: all .2s;
    }
    .navbar.navbar-default ul li a:hover {
      color: white;
    }
    .nav.navbar-nav,
    .nav.navbar-nav>li {
      float: none;
    }
    .navbar.navbar-default ul li:hover:after {
      right: 0;
      left: 0;
    }
    .nav-title {
      font-size: 14pt;
      margin:0;
      top: 35px;
      left: 50px;
      width: 100%;
      position: absolute;
      text-align: center;
      color: white;
      font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    }
    .navbar.navbar-default ul.dropdown-menu li,
    .navbar.navbar-default ul.dropdown-menu li a {
      position: relative;
      display: block;
    }
    #logo {
      padding-top: 2vh;
      padding-left: 20px;
      float: left;
    }
    .hero {
      background-image: url("https://static.pexels.com/photos/48727/pexels-photo-48727.jpeg");
      background-attachment: fixed;
      position:relative;
      text-align: center;
      width: 100%;
      max-width:100%;
      width: 100vw;
      height: 100%;
    }
    section {
      position: relative;
      height: 95vh;
    }
    .section1 {
      height: 100vh;
      text-align: center;
      color: white;
    }
    .section2 {
      background-color: #11B5E4;
      text-align: center;
      color: white;
    }
    .section3 {
      background-color: #FFFFFF;
      text-align: center;
      color: white;
    }
    .fa-angle-down {
      color: #4D5061;
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 0px;
    }
    .fa-angle-up {
      color: #4D5061;
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 0px;
    }
    .footer {
      height: 6vh;
      background-color: #4D5061;
      padding:0;
      right:0;
      bottom:0;
      left:0;
    }
    .footertext{
      font-size: 14pt;
      color: white;
      font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
      text-align: center;
    }
    .shape {
      content:url(http://i1126.photobucket.com/albums/l611/ldocherty1/IMG_0730_zpsiz4dqc47.jpg);
      border-radius: 25px;
      background:#4D5061;
      color:white;
      padding:3px;
      margin:150px auto 0 797px;
      width:250px;
      max-width:100%;
      height:250px;
      position: absolute;
    }
    .shape2 {
      background: linear-gradient(35deg, #4D5061, #4D5061);
      border-radius: 85px;
      color:white;
      opacity: 0.9;
      padding:0px;
      margin:410px auto 0 798px;
      width:250px;
      max-width:100%;
      height:40px;
      left:200;

      position: absolute;
    }
    </style>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try updating the head section with this meta tag

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

with in the head of the HTML file and have a look at [CSS Media Queries](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp) these help you change the style depending of the size of the screen and it very dynamic

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <html lang="en">
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Liam Docherty Digital Portfolio</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

  <style>
    body {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
    
    .navbar.navbar-default {
      background-color: #4D5061;
      height: 10vh;
      z-index: 100;
    }
    
    .navbar.navbar-default ul {
      list-style-type: none;
      text-align: right;
    }
    
    .navbar.navbar-default ul li {
      display: inline-block;
    }
    
    .dropdown-menu li {
      text-align: center
    }
    
    .dropdown .dropdown-menu {
      background-color: #4D5061;
    }
    
    .dropdown .dropdown-menu a {
      color: white;
    }
    
    .navbar.navbar-default ul li a {
      display: inline-block;
      padding: 3.5vh 8px 4px;
      color: white;
      text-decoration: none;
      font-size: 14pt;
      font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    }
    
    .navbar.navbar-default ul li:after {
      content: '';
      position: absolute;
      right: 50%;
      bottom: 0;
      left: 50%;
      height: 3px;
      background-color: #FFFFFF;
      border-radius: 9px;
      transition: all .2s;
    }
    
    .navbar.navbar-default ul li a:hover {
      color: white;
    }
    
    .nav.navbar-nav,
    .nav.navbar-nav>li {
      float: none;
    }
    
    .navbar.navbar-default ul li:hover:after {
      right: 0;
      left: 0;
    }
    
    .nav-title {
      font-size: 14pt;
      margin: 0;
      top: 35px;
      left: 50px;
      width: 100%;
      position: absolute;
      text-align: center;
      color: white;
      font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    }
    
    .navbar.navbar-default ul.dropdown-menu li,
    .navbar.navbar-default ul.dropdown-menu li a {
      position: relative;
      display: block;
    }
    
    #logo {
      padding-top: 2vh;
      padding-left: 20px;
      float: left;
    }
    
    .hero {
      background-image: url("https://static.pexels.com/photos/48727/pexels-photo-48727.jpeg");
      background-attachment: fixed;
      position: relative;
      text-align: center;
      width: 100%;
      max-width: 100%;
      width: 100vw;
      height: 100%;
    }
    
    section {
      position: relative;
      height: 95vh;
    }
    
    .section1 {
      height: 100vh;
      text-align: center;
      color: white;
    }
    
    .section2 {
      background-color: #11B5E4;
      text-align: center;
      color: white;
    }
    
    .section3 {
      background-color: #FFFFFF;
      text-align: center;
      color: white;
    }
    
    .fa-angle-down {
      color: #4D5061;
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 0px;
    }
    
    .fa-angle-up {
      color: #4D5061;
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 0px;
    }
    
    .footer {
      height: 6vh;
      background-color: #4D5061;
      padding: 0;
      right: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      left: 0;
    }
    
    .footertext {
      font-size: 14pt;
      color: white;
      font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
      text-align: center;
    }
    
    .profile.box {
      bottom: 0;
      height: 50%;
      left: 0;
      margin: auto;
      position: absolute;
      right: 0;
      top: 0;
      width: 50%;
    }
    
    .shape {
      border-radius: 25px;
      background: #4D5061;
      content: url(http://i1126.photobucket.com/albums/l611/ldocherty1/IMG_0730_zpsiz4dqc47.jpg);
      color: white;
      height: 250px;
      margin: auto;
      padding: 3px;
      width: 250px;
    }
    
    .shape2 {
      background: linear-gradient(35deg, #4D5061, #4D5061);
      border-radius: 85px;
      color: white;
      height: 40px;
      margin: 1% auto;
      opacity: 0.9;
      padding: 0px;
      width: 250px;
    }
  </style>

</head>

<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/60x60" alt="Your Brand Name"></a>
        <h1 class="nav-title">Liam Docherty's Digital Portfolio</h1>
      </div>
      <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li><a href="#">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">About Me <span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="#">Action</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#section3">Contact</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#">Something else here</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#">Separated link</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Units <span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="#">Action</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#">Another action</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#">Something else here</a>
              </li>

              <li><a href="#">Separated link</a>
              </li>

              <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Clients</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#contact-me">Contact Me</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.container-fluid -->
  </nav>


  <section id="section1" class="section1">
    <div class="hero">
      <div class="profile box">
        <div class="shape"></div>
        <div class="shape2">
          <p>kjjjjjjjjjkjjjkkjkj</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>





    <a href="#section2"><i class="fa fa-angle-down" style="font-size:100px;"></i></a>

  </section>
  <section id="section2" class="section2">


    <a href="#contact-me"> <i class="fa fa-angle-down" style="font-size:100px;"></i></a>

  </section>

  <section id="contact-me" class="contact_section section3">


    <a href="#section1"> <i class="fa fa-angle-up" style="font-size:100px;"></i></a>

  </section>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js" integrity="sha256-16cdPddA6VdVInumRGo6IbivbERE8p7CQR3HzTBuELA=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  <footer>
    <div class="footer">
      <h2 class="footertext">Copyright © 2017 Liam Docherty's Site. All rights reserved.</h2>
    </div>
  </footer>
</body>

</html>
```

Have a go at this; culprit for the annoying sizes are the margin added to `shape` and `shape2` `div`'s

Comment: Hi, thanks for the feedback I appreciate it. However, I tried using the meta tag you suggested nothing seemed to change. would you be able to help me change my CSS into using more bootstrap ways of doing what I want in order for my site content to fit on the users screen no matter which browser or screen size they're doing like the example above. I have really hit a brick wall and I'm super confused you can see I'm trying in my post.

Comment: Thanks for your time, you see you said "Have a go at this; culprit for the annoying sizes are the margin added to shape and shape2 div's" is this due to one of the shapes have a 1% added and the other one doesn't? In addition, when I also look at this on chrome & safari at the standard 100% view everything still looks out of placed? Am I looking to a 'webkit'?  I did try looking at the link you suggested but didn't have much luck, that's probably due to me only recently starting to learn this.

Comment: `.shape {
      margin:150px auto 0 797px;
    }
    .shape2 {
      margin:410px auto 0 798px;
    }` this is what your css used to be; since they are absolute margin references; they work fine for the screen size you were building it on. if the screen size changes it will add horizontal scroll bar to the smaller screen to keep the margin pixel sizes. My changes will place the `shape ` and `shape2` at the centre of the screen regardless of the size of the screen. That's why you get the `shape` and `shape2` on different places on different screen.

Comment: Other option is to use Media queries for most of the common screen sizes.`
 @media screen and (min-width: 1020px) {
    .shape { margin:150px auto 0 797px; } 
    .shape2 { margin:410px auto 0 798px; }
}` 
 
`@media screen and (min-width: 1280px) {
    .shape { margin:150px auto 0 797px; }
    .shape2 { margin:410px auto 0 798px; }
} `
Then you put the absolute margin values for that screen and they will kick in when the screen size matches. \n Try using the chrome developer tools to simulate different screen sizes. `CMD+Shift+i` to enable on your mac.

Answer (score 0):

First of all I would recommend you to learn more about the Bootstrap Grid for this. Bootstrap is an easy to use and install CSS-framework that is very good for developing **responsive** webpages (which is the term you are looking for).

If you want to do this yourself you can use **media-queries** in CSS for this.

**Example**
The CSS in the example below is only used on browserwindows that are between 520px and 699px. If the window size is not in this range this CSS is skipped.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 699px) and (min-width: 520px) {
    ul li a {
        padding-left: 30px;
        background: url(email-icon.png) left center no-repeat;
    }
}
```

This example is from w3schools. Look [here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_mediaqueries_ex.asp) for more information

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comment I'll try to include this within my code and I'll read up on the link you recommended me to check out. However,  would you be able to help me change my CSS into using more bootstrap ways of doing what I want in order for my site content to fit on the users screen no matter which browser or screen size they're doing like the example above. I have really hit a brick wall and I'm super confused you can see I'm trying in my post.

Comment: Ok. So the bootstrap grid essentially is a CSS-file that you can download an d add into your own HTML-file. You can download it or just include it via the CDN. This CSS-file defines some classes that you can use. Butt... you have to use them in a specific way. To learn about how to use the bootstrap grid see: https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/grid/

Comment: Also when using the media-queries change the viewport meta-tag as Praveen M described

Comment: `media screen and (max-width: 699px) and (min-width: 520px) {
    ul li a {
        padding-left: 30px;
        background: url(https://static.pexels.com/photos/48727/pexels-photo-48727.jpeg) left center no-repeat;
    }`  When I add this to my code why does all my CSS get overridden?

Comment: In the example you give you mis one } at the end. When using media queries your css goes BETWEEN { and } so if you use a { display: block; } then you would end up with two } at the end. Because you don't close the media query your browser probably 'thinks' that all your css belongs inside the query.